# Is it possible to programatically create a simple 3d object on Unreal?

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

Is there a way to create and use a simple 3d model on the Unreal Engine?

Comment: do you mean create a 3DS, MAX, or some FBX model realtime in max?

Comment: Any way that work. The model must work like any other model in the game. In this case, a sword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create the initial 3D asset in a third party tool and import it into the IDE. From there you can change the texture map, and manipulate the aesthetics in one way or another, but the initial 3D model should be in an external 3D format, and then placed as a prefab into your world.

Creating an object dynamically in UDK is cumbersome and requires lots of tweaking, and won't save much in terms of cost of resources. Especially if you want it to look good and more than just 3D meshes thrown together rudimentarily. It is possible, but almost not worth it, especially if you have 3DSMax, Maya, Cinema4D, MotionBuilder, or one of the other hundred tools available to do the grunt work for you.

Most 3D Engines (IE Unity, UDK, Torque, Cry and now Havok) support many formats, and especially the unversal FBX. You could even use google sketchup and export to DAE or FBX format to get it into your Engine. Grant it you lose a lot of the elements, but the basic 3D mesh stays relatively in tact.